# Adding local plugin in the left navigation menu in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I would add my local plugin in the left navigation menu. However, the code block I wrote in the lib.php is not running and not displaying my plugin in the navigation menu.

Could you please help me?
Here is my lib.php

```
<?php
function local_glossary_extend_navigation(global_navigation $navigation){

$main_node = $navigation->add(get_string('glossary','local_glossary'), '/local/glossary/');
$main_node->nodetype=1;
$main_node->collapse = false;
$main_node->forceopen = true;
$main_node->isexpendable = false;
$main_node->showinflatnavigation = true;
```

}

This is my version.php

```
<?php
$plugin->version  = 2020061510.00;
$plugin->requires = 2020060900;
$plugin->component = 'local_glossary';

$plugin->cron     = 0;
$plugin->release = '1.0';

$plugin->maturity = MATURITY_STABLE;
```

This is my index.php

```
$PAGE->set_url('/local/glossary/index.php');
$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
$PAGE->requires->jquery();
require_login();

$strpagetitle=get_string('glossary','local_glossary');
$strpageheading=get_string('glossary','local_glossary');
$PAGE->set_title($strpagetitle);
$PAGE->set_heading($strpageheading);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Site Admin" menu?

If so, you should add menus via the `/local/glossary/settings.php` file

There is an answer here -  [Moodle - how to add navigation menu in left side menu bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495865/moodle-how-to-add-navigation-menu-in-left-side-menu-bar/23499812#23499812)

For more details see - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API#Settings_navigation